# Visual Studio Text Box Wrap Function

Tags: visual-studio, textbox, word-wrap

How can I make my text wrap automatically to the next line when I am writing text in a textbox rather than keeps on typing in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your text box multi-line in the property settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that but although the textbox grows the typing keeps going in a straight line!